# Results of calculating with Sum (expression) give a wrong number in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a column which should calculate some numbers and sometimes it gives me the correct sum and sometimes it doesn't. I don't know why! Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I used this expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!TotalEmployees.Value)
```

When I don't choose something from filters on the top , it will give me the correct sum: 

 [image: s]

And when I choose something from the filters on the top, for example between 2 dates, it will give me wrong the sum: 
[image]

**Parameters & Body of report :**

```
@EndDateFrom
@EndDateTo
```

[image: b1]

Comment: Can you post your dataset query and parameters.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - Yes Sir , i just update my post with dataset & parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue with changing my query ,where all calculating (AVG , Sum &.. ) happens in query , instead reporting services do it for me .. after that i got the correct number:

```
SELECT t1.Departments, count(t1.id), avg(t1.age),sum(t1.TotalEmployees)/count(t1.id)
    AS TotalEmpl FROM (<current_query>) AS t1 <br> GROUP BY t1.Departments
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to be wary of your grouping. I'm willing to bet you're stuck inside of a group which is filtering your results.

If you are using Report Builder 2016, you can right click your last row and select "Add Total". This will generally automatically generate a row that gets the sum of all fields in your group.

Comment: tnx for your comment Lucky .. i tried but is not working

Comment: Hey, I noticed you are displaying the AVERAGE of total employees in the rows and in the total you are putting the SUM of total employees. I think you might get the right results if you show SUM in each row or SUM of AVERAGE in total row?

Comment: I agree with Lucky, At the detail you are getting the average but at the toal level you are getting the sum. if you want the sum of the numbers above you need to do the SUM of Average, basically whatever is in your detail row expression, wrap it in a SUM().

Comment: Tnx to both of you , do you mean something like this > =Sum(Avg(Fields!TotalEmployees.Value))

Comment: to know how many emp work in each departments , i used =Avg(Fields!TotalEmployees.Value) and result will be something like this ;. 2 emp works in IT department , 3 emp works in IT2 department and for total level i wanna  something like this ;. (2+3)=5 not something like  (2+3)/2= 2.5

Comment: In that case you want to use SUM. Change your rows to [SUM(TotalEmployees)] . Then run the report and check your numbers to see if they match up right. AVG will give the average (the (2+3)/2=2.5 equation) which sounds like you don't want.

Comment: @Lucky . its dosent matter wat expr i used , when i choose btw 2 dates ,it gives a wrong number

Comment: OK if you have your expression corrected, right click your [Sum(TotalEmployees)] in the row and pick Add Total. If that doesn't do it for you, I have no idea what's wrong!

Comment: Not working :D :D me too brother , i have no idea whats wrong . i aslo double check everything but still i dont where problem is.

Comment: You might want to try making a new table with the wizard and only adding the department name and employee count. Then you can add in the other columns after the fact if that works properly. Like I said before, the groups can give some weird and unexpected results sometimes.

Comment: i tried before ,but its not working . instead i did it something else and works for me and its give me correct number . i changed my query, where all calculating (AVG , Sum &..) happens in query instead  reporting services do it for me.